# Mastering inorganic chemistry for university

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, books

I want book recommendations for inorganic chemistry. I want to learn it in a way that every behavior or equation of elements seems logical and can be explained.
Is there any book of that sort? It would be better if it mentions minute details as well. 
Note : I have completed by secondary school.

Comment: If question is not up to the mark you make close or down vote it but please mention the book which you think might help me.

Comment: "in a way that every behavior or equation of elements seems logical and can be explained." Welcome to chemistry - a somewhat related series of special cases.

Answer (score -2):

Concise inorganic chemistry by J D Lee is a great book for this. It explains everything easily but in great detail.

Comment: I do not understand why this answer was downvoted?

Comment: Can you please hilight it's features that makes it;s different ?